# How can I convert object to XML without serialization tools

Tags: c#, xml, object

I need to convert this class to a XML file but for some reasons I can't use .NET serialization libraries. Is there any way I can convert this class without this tools?

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

I know about `XmlSerializer` and tried this already and get result but I need to do this without `XmlSerializer`:

```
Product product = new Product();
var stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(product.GetType());
serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, product);
return stringwriter.ToString();
```

Comment: It's hard to suggest any solution if we don't know what are the "some reasons" that prevent you from using standard .net features?

Comment: Why you can't use `XmlSerializer`? Xml - is text format, you can surely write some *text* into file (containing xml tags).

Comment: What **can** you use?  [`DataContractSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx)?  [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)?  Or [`XmlDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, it is a way to achieve that by using XDocument class.

Comment: I need to implement my own method this is why I don't want to use this libraries.

Comment: And if we implement it for you, that is ok? :) It's hardly your own method then.

Comment: @Esko No I don't want someone implement it for me I just need a help so that I can implement it myself.

Comment: You can see the XMLSerializer implementation which will maybe give you a few ideas on how to implement it on your own : https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Xml.XmlSerializer/src/System/Xml/Serialization/XmlSerializer.cs

Answer (score 1):

You'll just need to use a `StringBuilder` and concatenate strings:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
```

And then:

```
builder.AppendFormat("<instance property=\"{0}\" />", instance.Property);
```

If you need to support a circular reference scenation where: Product => Category => Product, then you'll need to use a mechanims that can create a unique runtime identity for each instance, so you don't serialize the same object more than once (check the [ObjectIDGenerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.objectidgenerator(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

> ***You may try a abstract class as per your requirment eg.***

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Product p = new Product();
            var x = p.ToXml();
            Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public abstract class XmlSerializable
    {
        public XElement ToXml() {
            XElement elm = new XElement(this.GetType().Name);
            this.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().ForEach(p => elm.Add(new XElement(p.Name, p.GetValue(this))));

            return elm;
        }
    }

    public class Product :XmlSerializable
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Desc { get; set; }
        public float Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try code like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {

             Product product = new Product()
             {
                 id = 123,
                 title = "A Long Way Home",
                 desc = "Welcome",
                 price = 456.78F,
                 category = new Category() { name = "John" }
             };

             XElement xProduct = new XElement("Product", new object[] {
                 new XElement("Id", product.id),
                 new XElement("Title", product.title),
                 new XElement("Description", product.desc),
                 new XElement("Price", product.price),
                 new XElement("Category", product.category)
             });
        }

    }
    public class Product
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string desc { get; set; }
        public float price { get; set; }
        public Category category { get; set; }
    }
    public class Category
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
 }
```